# Android MediaRecorder creating empty files

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder

I am using a MediaRecorder to record video through the front camera. This works on most phones I tested on, but on a Galaxy S3, the preview is blank and it doesn't record any video (saves empty 32 byte files).

Here is my configuration for the MediaRecorder:

```
    @Override
    public void startRecord() {
            camera.stopPreview();
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            camera.unlock();

            recorder.setCamera(camera);

            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            recorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
            recorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
            recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
            recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(profile.audioBitRate);
            recorder.setAudioChannels(profile.audioChannels);
            recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(profile.audioSampleRate);
            recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

            recorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
            recorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);

            try {
                    recorder.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            recorder.start();
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you tried setProfile method? Does it work? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setProfile%28android.media.CamcorderProfile%29

Comment: @lassana My code is essentially a customized setProfile method. The setProfile method does the same thing except with the profile's parameters instead of my own in some places.

Comment: I have same problem with Camera2Video example using Nexus5... It keeps creating empty video files.